# Can move the image to SDcard when install the android apps?

Tags: android, app2sd

Just like the "Angry Bird", the apps is up to 10MB when downloaded form market
After installation, the apps will only remain around 1.92MB (Seen form Setting --> Applications --> Manage Application)

Why they can do that? 
My apps have many picture, it makes the file very large, 
I want all picture auto move to SDcard when install the apps.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Maybe they download the images from internet once the app is installed, that's a common technique.